# Convert input char array to full integer number in C

Tags: arrays, c, char

I am trying to create a function that scans the user input and shows the counted integer numbers and add them. For example the user input would be 'room 2301 next to 12 street' the function would count the number 2301 as one, and 12 as two and add them, 2313 which is the sum and returns it. so the return would be count=2, sum= 2313. However, I am having an issue with the logic behind the function. Currently my function takes the numbers separately, eg. 2302 = 2,3,0,2.

Here is my code:

```
void num_count(char array[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int tmp[20];
    tmp_size = 20;

    while (array[i] != '\0') {
        if (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9') {
            tmp[i] = (array[i] - '0'); 

            //not sure what to do here

            count++;
            sum += (array[i] - '0');
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

currently I try to put it into a temp array but not really sure what to do next. Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: 1. Each digit is a power of 10.  Adjust your math accordingly.

Comment: 2.  You should probably be using [`isdigit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/), not `array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9'`

Comment: @RobertHarvey : I'm not 100% sure but I suspect `isdigit` function is nothing more that a single `if` block like: `int isdigit(char c) { if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return 1; else return 0; }`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should begin from the end of the array to the beginning.
When you encounter a digit you have to sum this first digit, then iterate the next character and if it is a digit you have to sum digit x10, the next one: digit x100...
When the next character is not a digit, reset the multiplier and count++.

```
   if(isDigit){
    sum+= digit*multiplier;
    multiplier*=10;
    }
    else {
    multiplier=1;
    }
```

I don't inlcude the count part.

Answer (score 0):

- If you only need the sum, you do not have to save it as `char` in a char array (in your code it is named `tmp[]`), but you can directly convert it to integer (assuming no overflow will occur).
- Every time you detect the first numeric character, you should reset the `tmp` to zero and continue multiplying by 10 before adding the next numeric value, until you detect a non-numeric character.
- edit: I think the function should return the `sum`. So, you'd better change the function decoration as well (and add a `return sum` line).

```
int num_count(char array[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int tmp;

    while (array[i] != '\0') {
        if (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9') {
            tmp = 0;

            while (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9') {
                tmp = tmp * 10 + array[i] - '0';
                i++;
            }

            sum += tmp;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet to extract the individual words of the string, check if the extracted word is a number, and, if a number, calculate the sum and increase the count.

```
int i;
int j;
int count;
int sum;
char *chars;
char *pChar;
int len;
int isNum;
for (i=0, count=0, sum=0; i<strlen(array);) {
   pChar = strchr(array[i], ' ');
   len = pChar - array[i];
   chars = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
   strncpy(chars, array[i], len);
   chars[len] = '\0';
   for (j =0, isNum = 1; j<len; j++) {
      if (!isdigit(chars[j])) {
         isNum=0;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (isNum) {
     count++;
     sum += atoi(chars);
   }
   free(chars);
   if (strchr(array[pChar - array + 1] != NULL)
      i = (pChar - array) + 1;
   else
      break;
}
```